# Linux / OS X tar incompatibility – tarballs created on OS X give errors when untarred in Linux

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, tar

When I tar up files on my Macbook and untar them in Linux, I repeatedly get the following warnings/errors:

```
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
 tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
 tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Fortunately, this does NOT affect the files stored in the archive, which are restored perfectly.  However, it does cause problems in a number of scenarios, especially when dealing with build processes where the non-zero failure code returned by 'tar' causes builds and installs to stop unnecessarily.

How can I get OS X to build tar files that play nicely with the rest of the Linux world?

Also, for bonus points, there exists a publicly distributed tar file with these issues.  Is there any way to get Linux to handle the tar file gracefully *without* changing the way it was originally compressed?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I Googled for the error message and it seems like a BSD tar vs. GNU `tar` issue.

Install GNU `tar` if you can on Mac OS and use that to create the `tar`.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6 uses a BSD tar by default but also ships with a gnutar at `/usr/bin/gnutar`.

Comment: @Ned.  Thx.  that's good info.

Comment: FYI : /usr/bin/gnutar is not shipped anymore with Mac OS X (at least as of Mavericks)

Comment: sudo port install gnutar
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm tar 
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/gnutar tar

Comment: If using MacPorts, you can also just put /opt/local/libexec/gnubin/ at the top of your PATH rather than removing anything from /usr/bin or manually creating symlinks.

Comment: If using Homebrew:  `brew install gnu-tar`

Answer (score 71):

If you are using Mavericks or newer, then gnutar is no longer included by default.

The work around, if you use homebrew, is to execute the following:

```
brew install gnu-tar
```

You can then use the command `gtar` for linux compatability.

---

If you want to replace `tar` with `gtar`, simply replace the symlink

```
tar --version
ll `which tar`
sudo unlink `which tar`
sudo ln -s `which gtar` /usr/bin/tar
tar --version
```

To restore the original tar provided with Mac Os X, run the above commands but replace `which gtar` with `which bsdtar`

Source:
https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/issues/576

Comment: No need to unlink anymore, as brew instructs, you can just add this to your PATH in `.bashrc` (or your equivalent):
`PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

Comment: Or just create a `tar` link in `/usr/local/bin` by `cd /usr/local/bin ; ln -s gtar tar` - possibly the simplest option

Answer (score 33):

GNU tar doesn't like some of the optional information the default OSX BSD tar includes.

GNU tar will let you suppress those warnings with the option:

```
--warning=no-unknown-keyword
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_27.html

Note that BSD tar doesn't support that flag so if you need to run the same unpacking code on all platforms you can use something like:

```
isGnuTar=$(tar --version | grep -q 'gnu')
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Detected GNU tar"
    tar --warning=no-unknown-keyword -zxf my.tar.gz
else
    tar -zxf my.tar.gz
fi
```

Comment: this should be the right answer because it doesn't involve installing an entirely new tool for the sake of suppressing a single warning.

Answer (score 10):

To extract the tar file properly without any errors on a Linux system you could use bsdtar.

`sudo apt-get install bsdtar`

Then use as normal.

`bsdtar -xvf file.tar` where `file.tar` is the tar file you want to extract.

**Source:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tar/+bug/129314

Alternatively you can also use GNOME file roller.

Answer (score 7):

```
COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar cf filename.tar
```

or

```
tar --disable-copyfile cf filename.tar
```

This is the least discoverable feature of tar on OS X that I am personally aware of.

See also [Why do I get files like ._foo in my tarball on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/61185/why-do-i-get-files-like-foo-in-my-tarball-on-os-x)

---

Edit: it looks like this might only stop the creation of the unwanted `._foo`-type files, it doesn't stop the header creation (at least on Yosemite/10.10); thanks commenters for pointing it out. However, (for the bonus points:) you can gracefully handle such tarballs by extracting them like this:

```
tar xf filename.tar --pax-option=delete=SCHILY.*,delete=LIBARCHIVE.*
```

This worked using gnu tar 1.15.1, which is pretty old! Alternatively, you can use pax instead, which (for me) throws the extra info into a `PaxHeader` directory, but at least exits without error:

```
pax -rf filename.tar
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not appear to stop the extended header keyword warnings when untarring with gnutar.

Comment: Neither of these seems to work on Yosemite (`tar --version` indicates `bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3`).  Also I need a dash before `cf` in the latter case.

Answer (score 4):

MacOSX comes with gnutar already.  If you want a quick and dirty solution add this to `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias tar='gnutar'
```

and run `source ~/.bash_profile` to update

Additionally, OSX ships with both GNU and BSD tar.  So you can also unlink the ref of tar from bsd to gnu:

```
sudo unlink /usr/bin/tar;
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gnutar /usr/bin/tar
```

Comment: Why in `/etc/hosts`? `/etc/hosts` is for host/IP mapping, right?

Comment: what @BenjiWiebe said.  The even odder bit is editing /etc/hosts.  I think you meant ~/.bashrc

Comment: On OS X, `.bashrc` isn't loaded for Terminal sessions. You need `.bash_profile`, since a login shell is started with a new Terminal window. /cc @BenjiWiebe

Comment: Correct :-) I was also working in /etc/hosts at that time so it spewed onto the keyboard.  Good catch

Answer (score 3):

Thank you. This thread was very useful. If you are using MacPorts here is a quick howto:

`sudo port install gnutar`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin/tar /usr/bin/gnutar`

`sudo ln -s /opt/local/libexec/gnubin/tar /usr/bin/gnutar`

Add the following line to /Users/[yourname]/.profile

`alias tar='/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/tar'`

Quit und and restart your Terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

[Use the `--no-xattrs` option](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74373784/revisions) when creating the archive:

```
tar cfz yoyodyne.tgz --no-xattrs /tmp/john_bigbootie/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I used Google search, but top three link confirmed what I suspected

1. Bug in your tar AND/OR
2. Incompatibility between the two tar utilities
   <strike>See [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tar/+bug/129314). There someone reports that "Using "bsdtar -xvf" worked."</strike>

**Edit:** You are on Mac system, I thought other way round. You will need to use gnutar, it should be installed already, if not get it installed. Of course, you can look at other links by searching yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, Mac's built-in tar binary adds a bunch of extra stuff that CentOS doesn't like. To fix this do the following:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/tar /usr/bin/darwintar
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gnutar /usr/bin/tar
ls -l /usr/bin/tar
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's one way.  I solved the GNU/BSD issue more comprehensively in https://github.com/ddopson/dotfiles.  I have ~/bin/coreutils early in the path and there's small shims in there like https://github.com/ddopson/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/coreutils/tar that pick the correct executable based on linux vs Mac and if the COREUTILS environment variable is set

Comment: You might want to modify your instructions to tell people to check for the existence of /usr/bin/gnutar before moving their working tar.  Newbies can find this using google and not know how to un-break their system.

Comment: That's probably not a good idea, for a couple of reasons.  1) Now Apple packages don't know where to find the native tar, the tar that knows how to handle Apple file attributes.  2) If you must use GNU tar, the proper place to put it is ahead in your search path, like /usr/local/bin, or something, and 3)  It's probably safer still to call the foreign `tar` program gnutar to avoid confusing software expecting a Mac to act like a Mac.  $0.02.  -Erik

Answer (score 0):

On MAC OSX install gnu-tar

```
brew install gnu-tar
```

then create your linux compatible tar with:

```
gtar -c -f your_tar_file files
```

Or you can create your archive with pax format

```
tar -c --format pax -f your_tar_file files
```